# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - After installing 5.0.6.1 fix pack, Studio version is v6.0 instead of v5.0.6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I was using worklight studio 5.0.6.20130311-0918, but for iOS7 support the plug-in requires updating.

I followed these instructions:

1. In Eclipse, `Help -> Install New Software...`
2. Added '5.0.6.1-WL-StudioP2-IF201309171955.zip' Repository archive and named it 'WL_5061_FIX':
   [image]
3. Closed the window and went to `Help -> Check for Updates`. After checking is finish, it show the Available Updates:
   [image]
4. Clicked next, waited for the update to finish and restarted Eclipse. I then went to check the Worklight version, and it shows the Worklight Studio version as v6:
   [image]

It should be worklight 5.0.6100. Why does it show 6.0?

Comment: What do you see in Help > Install New Software... >> Already installed? 5.0.6.1 or 6.0?

Comment: It shows 5.0.6.1 (http://imageshack.us/a/img407/1988/u37u.png), but  why in Eclipse > about Eclipse >> tap worklight icon shows worklight 6 (http:imageshack.us/a/img690/9444/vr59.png) ,  and in my project application-descriptor.xml the tag application's attribute platformVersion change to 6.0.0

Comment: A bug... we'll fix it. Everything else works for you?

Comment: Thanks you Idan.  
Does it means : If my client wants to put the app to apple store quickly (in Nov/Dec) there is only way -- direct upgrade to worklight 6.

Comment: If you build your app with the fix for 5.0.6.1 that adds iOS 7 support, then it's fine - you can continue using 5.0.6.1; Worklight 6.0 offers a different set of improvements (including the fix for iOS 7).

Comment: Ok, Does it means I can use this upgrade version(5.0.6.1-WL-StudioP2-IF201309171955.zip) to build success in iOS7 although the application-descriptor.xml attribute platformVersion is 6.0.0. or should I wait for new fix pack for 5.0.61x

Comment: If the application-descriptor.xml shows you 6.0.0 then something is not right at all.

Can you try the same with a FRESH Eclipse and workspace and see if it happens still?

Comment: How to FRESH Eclipse and workspace?
I try to create new workspace and new project but it still shows 6.0.0 in application-descriptor.xml

Comment: I mean, use a new copy of Eclipse; Download it again.

Comment: Please also make sure that if you are using the Consumer Edition, you DO NOT mix it with the Enterprise Edition. You cannot mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you see in `Help > Install New Software... > Already installed`? 5.0.6.1 or 6.0?

I believe you will see there 5.0.6100...
This is a defect in the plug-in, but everything else should work fine for you.

Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and help !!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue as well, and my workaround was to disable 'Contact all updates sites during install to find required software'.